# Trying to Pın Background for login screen

Tags: user-interface, flutter, background

[crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFDPO.png)

I'm trying to make user interface for login screen but when i try to open keyboard to set input for e-mail or password keyboard pops up and background picture moves up too. How can i prevent it happen ?

```
     class MyPageState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/backgroundd.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 280),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 280,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                          hintText: "please enter your e-mail",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          helperStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 50,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Scafold widget by **resizeToAvoidBottomInset**

```
 Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, //add this line
      body: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
            ],
          ))
  );
```